# Display Options for Text Descriptions - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, filepath, jeditorpane, listselectionlistener

### Okay, I have this program I am writing and would love some oversight please.

---

This program of sorts, uses a *JList* and *JListSelectionListener* to output a number of images onto, 1/2 vertically-split *JPanes*. Of these *JPanes*, as mentioned beforehand; one displays the images and in the bottom *JPanel*, a *JEditorPane* reads text. For the *JEditorPane*, I have an `HTML doc.` styled and being read from. This in theory, is my description of each image. Except, I cannot redirect the *JEditorPane* as too, read from aforementioned `HTML` files whose `URLs` or `paths` are accessed via a *String Array[]*.

### Main Points/Questions (tldr;)

---

1. How do I have this *JEditorPane* read from a different `HTML` file each time a new image is selected from the *JList*?
2. Should I be using a *JTextPane* or something else instead? Only, too my knowledge, styling might be in-or-out of the question. So, what am I doing wrong or differently and should be?

### Code

---

```
private String[] fileName = { "htmlDoc1", "htmlDoc2", "htmlDoc3", "htmlDoc4" };

protected JScrollPane createEditorList() {
    JEditorPane editorPane = createEditorPane(fileName[list.getSelectedIndex()]);
    JScrollPane editorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorPane);
    editorScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    editorScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 145));
    editorScrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
    return editorScrollPane;
}

private JEditorPane createEditorPane(String file) {
    JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
    editorPane.setEditable(false);
    java.net.URL helpURL = Bobbleheads.class.getResource("/images/bobbleheads/" + file + ".html");
    if (helpURL != null) {
        try {
            editorPane.setPage(helpURL);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Attempted to read a bad URL: " + helpURL);
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + fileName);
    }

    return editorPane;
}

public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    JList<?> list = (JList<?>) e.getSource();
    updateLabel(imageNames[list.getSelectedIndex()]);
    createEditorPane(fileName[list.getSelectedIndex()]);
}
```

### Thank you too everyone, contributing any way possible!

Comment: Does the code keep a reference to the `JEditorPane`? If so, this should be a simple task. I must admit that there is a lot of the question(s) I do not understand. The use of particular words is ..interesting. Let the code do the (more) talking. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Was not sure how to post code directly as I am using the SO iPhone app. However, my question of, "How do I have this JEditorPane read from a different HTML file each time a new image is selected from the JList?" is focused on my main point. Other questions just alluded as to, another method or class I should be ascertaining from. Examples: JTextPane or others I simply haven't thought of. Thank you!

Comment: *"Was not sure how to post code directly as I am using the SO iPhone app."* Well, work it out. As it stands, I'm voting to close for 'lack of MCVE' given we cannot realistically answer the question without it.

Comment: No, no wait! Just pasted some spaghetti, wait please!

Comment: It looks like you are creating a brand-new editor pane when the selection is changed, and then forgetting about it (not using the return value).   Instead you should split your createEditorPane into two functions.  The first creates the editor.  The second loads content into the *existing* editor, and is what is called by the `valueChanged` callback.

Comment: *"wait please!"* Does that mean the uncompilable code snippet in the edit will be replaced with an MCVE / SSCCE? I can already spot problems in the snippet. One is purely conceptual, in calling the argument to `createEditorPane(..` a `file` when it is a resource path that will end up as an URL. The deeper problem is that the code is not retaining a reference to a single `JEditorPane`, as outlined by @AJNeufeld.

Comment: Got you, working it up. Will report back! Thanks

Comment: I have overcome it, thanks @ AJNeufeld & @Andrew Thompson! Serious, wish I could show you more of how it looks but I am here to answer this question! What you said worked unbelievably! Got a Stack Overflow error changing things around but once it set in, compiler blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Crunching in a few methods solved this Java singleton. With the outstanding help from AJNeufeld, Andrew Thompson & Stack Overflow of course!**

**Heres how:**

---

Original *methods* for change:

```
protected JScrollPane createEditorList() {
private JEditorPane createEditorPane(String file) {
```

and the `public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {` *method* were replaced with and replicated into these newer *code blocks*.

**Code:**

---

New, rescripted *methods*:

```
protected JScrollPane makeAEditorPane() {
    JScrollPane editorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(makeAEditorList());
    editorScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    editorScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 145));
    editorScrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10, 10));

    return editorScrollPane;
}

protected JEditorPane makeAEditorList() {
    editorPane = new JEditorPane();
    editorPane.setEditable(false);

    return editorPane;
}

private void feedEditor(String name) {
    URL helpURL = Bobbleheads.class.getResource("/images/bobbleheads/" + name + ".html");

    if (helpURL != null) {
        try {
            editorPane.setPage(helpURL);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Attempted to read a bad URL: " + helpURL);
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: TextSampleDemoHelp.html");
    }
}

public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    JList<?> list = (JList<?>) e.getSource();
    updateLabel(imageNames[list.getSelectedIndex()]);
    feedEditor(htmlDocs[list.getSelectedIndex()]);

}
```

**Understanding what has changed:**

---

1. Of the two original *methods*, three new *methods* were deduced. `createEditorList()` & `createEditorPane(String file)` became `makeAEditorPane()`, `makeAEditorList()` & `feedEditor(String name)`. Simply by splitting up the *components* *`editorScrollPane`* & *`editorPane`* during formation thanks to, @AJNeufeld.
2. Very next, the new *method* `feedEditor(String name),` did exactly what its name implies. Feeds the initiation of our *URL* here, allocating a *HTML file* for the *`editorPane`* to derive and *load* thanks to, @Andrew Thompson.
3. Accessing the *method*: `feedEditor(htmlDocs[list.getSelectedIndex()]);`, inside of the `valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)` *method,* paved the way for an *event* to occur. An *event* between a *JList* known as *`list`*.

**Wrapping things up...**

---

Now, the *event* brought a change in the *URL* discussed on earlier. Here, it is relatively simply put; allowing for switching between *JList selections*, activates *HTML files* located as *project resources*.

That's it! Thank you everybody and stay safe.

Comment: I’m glad you got your program working.  Now, click the grey check-box to the left of this answer to indicate that it solves the problem, and closes the question.  (As a bonus, you earn progress towards the “self-learner” badge.)